# oauth "Invalid bot parent table"

Tags: notion-api

After I select one or many pages and click on **Allow Access** I am getting a small Notion popup with an error "**Invalid bot parent table**".

#### Steps to reproduce

1. Go to `https://api.notion.com/v1/oauth/authorize?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=MY_REDIRECT_URL&scope=all&response_type=code&response_mode=query`
2. Once a popup opens, I click on **Select pages**
3. Select one or many pages, or even the whole workspace
4. Click on **Allow access**
5. A small popup (alert box) with an error **Invalid bot parent table** appears and I get response `MY_REDIRECT_URL/?error=server_error&state=`

*I am confident that this issue originates from the Notion itself as I verified it in an isolated environment as well, using https://oauthdebugger.com/*

Did anyone have a similar error? How did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue due to a temporary outage of the OAuth service on Notion. It has been resolved.